# How to make woocommerce single product page Additional information Tab attributes name Clickable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, attributes, product

My question is How to make woocommerce single product page Additional information Tab attributes name Clickable. Please review this screen shot -> http://nimb.ws/8PyQbM

If user click on "Rose" then i want to open Rose attributes page. So URL is `SITEURL/?filter_color=rose`

So if any one have idea for this solution then please update me.

Thanks,
Ketan Patel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need any custom code for this. If the attribute is public, WooCommerce will now show a link instead by default.

[image]

You can enable archive then attribute link automatically come in additional tab.

Comment: Yes, it's work for me. Before i have no idea. Woocommerce added this nice features for attaributes.

Thanks.